# iOS - vary for traits for landscape and portrait fails

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

So i am trying to locate a view inside my VC using auto layout.
In the story board it looks great:
In landscape the view in the middle of the view(x and y)
[image]

In portrait it is in the middle of x but in the bottom of the view:
[image]

Yet in the phone it is ok in the portrait:
[image]

but in landscape it is wrong:
[image]

The steps to build it used by me are as follow:

1.gave the view width and height

2.pressed vary for traits in portrait and add constraints

3.In landscape pushed vary for traits and gave the constraints i needed

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, 
So the problem wasn't in the constraints or the vary for trait but in the size of the device.
We have deferents groups of sizes: 4.7,5.5,5.8,6.5 and ipads.
I did the traits on the wrong group, once i changed it to the appropriate one it worked like a charm.